Filament and Filement shield assign role to user using relationship
i have user resource which is implemented with  filamnet shiled
and now i required another resource Employee with Employee Model whete user_id is the foreign key from user table
i am trying to asign roles using below code
Forms\Components\Group::make()
                    ->schema([

                        Forms\Components\Section::make('Associations')
                            ->schema([
                                Select::make('user.roles')
                                    ->relationship('user.roles', 'name')
                                    ->label('Select Role')
                                    ->native(false)
                                    ->required()

                            ]),
                    ])

i am trying to assign role for user.
i am using below code for creating user before create employee
protected function mutateFormDataBeforeCreate(array $data): array
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        $data['user_id'] = $user->id;

        return $data;
    }

